# How to design and display a UIView overlay

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, overlay

Hi guys here is the question: i've a MapView with a button and i'd like to trigger that button with an overlay view that fill the entire screen (beside of the navigation bar).

Is there a way i can design the overlay in Storyboard and connect it to the button with some kind of custom segue or i've to design it programmatically and also write the code for the animation??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the fact that this view i would like to present isn't reused in other view controllers i solved this by adding a UIView to the Storyboard view controller and set the hidden property to YES. The button trigger the value and present the view.

Thank you all for your tips!

Answer (score 3):

This is the quick and dirty way, using auto layout:

```
UIView * view = [UIView new];
busyView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:busyView];
[self.superview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[view]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:@{@"view": view}]];
[self.superview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:@{@"view": view}]];
```

This will add an overlay view on your main window, but pay attention:

- window doesn't handle rotations, so if your view contain something and you rotate the device everything will stay in the same place.
- it covers the whole screen

Comment: Ok but do i have to design my UIView programmatically like UIView *view = [UIView alloc] initWith Blablablabla??? I know it sounds lazy but if i could design it in StoryBoard could be a charm and timesaving

Comment: You could put it in a separate xib file and use loadNibNamed

Comment: @AlessandroLucarini in storyboard you can create an overlay view and keep it hidden, but it will always be contained in the containing view controller's view. That means that if you are in a nag controller this view will be vie under the navbar. In storyboard you can also create a view controller to be used as an overlay and this will cover the whole screen (in the most cases)